# Advertising with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ads, adsense

Let us suppose we have a site entirely written on Silverlight. All navigation occurs inside the SL application and data comes from services.

I want to add advertisement in the app that will change on each navigation in the app (ultimately the ad should be relevant to the current content).

**So how to add advertisement to such kind of web applications?**

Am I right that there are two major problems to do this?

1. Render html advertisement in silverlight.
2. Support relevance (in case of relevant ads like **Google AdSense**).

AFAIK, there are silverlight controls solving the first point.

I will appreciate any ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would segment part of the page to use for ads [like this](http://charette.com/journalist/) or you can used a native Silverlight ad rotator [like this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightAdRotator).

Comment: Thank you! How can I integrate Silverlight Ad Rotator with Google AdSense or Microsoft Advertising or so?

Comment: You can't at this time - because those two solutions are self-contained solutions.  If you manage your own advertiser relationships, then you can use the Silverlight ad rotator that I built.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the ads that are being displayed are without context. Seemingly that's one unfortunate side-effect of this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of overlaying HTML over your Silverlight app using Visual WebGUI:

[How to embed HTML inside a Visual WebGui Silverlight application](http://weblogs.asp.net/visualwebgui/archive/2008/07/31/how-to-embed-html-inside-a-visual-webgui-silverlight-application.aspx)